# Deriving solution $x$ from system of linear equations ($Ax=b$) for variable dimension $n$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the solution $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ for the following system of linear equations:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(a_1+a_2)x_1-a_2x_2&=a_1\\
-a_{2j-1}x_{j-1}+(a_{2j-1}+a_{2j})x_{j}-a_{2j}x_{j+1}&=0\\
-a_{2n-1}x_{n-1}+(a_{2n-1}+a_{2n})x_{n}&=0
\end{aligned}
$$

Clearly, I can rewrite this into

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
(a_1+a_2) & -a_2      & \\
-a_3      & (a_3+a_4) & -a_4 \\
& & \ddots \\
& &-a_{2n-3}      & (a_{2n-3}+a_{2n-2}) & -a_{2n-2} \\
& & &-a_{2n-1}      & (a_{2n-1}+a_{2n})
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
 \\
\vdots \\
 \\
x_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Actually, I'm mostly interested in the value $x_1$. I was able to solve the system using SageMath for some values $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and from observation I deduced the formula

$$x_1=\frac{\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n-j}a_{2k-1}\big)\big(\prod_{l=n+1-j}^na_{2l}\big)}{\sum_{j=0}^n\big(\prod_{k=1}^{n-j}a_{2k-1}\big)\big(\prod_{l=n+1-j}^na_{2l}\big)}$$

However, I would like to verify this formula for sure, even though it seems right for some values of $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is there a good way how I could verify this?

Any hint or help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe use Cramer's rule?

Comment: There is also a formula for determinants of tridiagonal matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant With this and using Cramer's rule, I think, I will be able to get the result from induction. Thank you for your hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Numerical experiment**

Writing in *Wolfram Mathematica 13.0*:

```
a[x_] := ToExpression[SubscriptBox["a", ToString[x]]]
nmax = 40;
Timing[
 num1 = RecurrenceTable[{f[n] == (a[2 n] + a[2 n - 1]) f[n - 1] -
                                  a[2 n - 1] a[2 n - 2] f[n - 2],
                         f[1] == a[1],
                         f[2] == a[1] (a[3] + a[4])},
                         f[n], {n, nmax}];
 den1 = RecurrenceTable[{f[n] == (a[2 n] + a[2 n - 1]) f[n - 1] -
                                  a[2 n - 1] a[2 n - 2] f[n - 2],
                         f[1] == a[1] + a[2],
                         f[2] == (a[1] + a[2]) (a[3] + a[4]) - a[2] a[3]},
                         f[n], {n, nmax}];
]
```

> 226.406 s

```
a[x_] := ToExpression[SubscriptBox["a", ToString[x]]]
nmax = 40;
Timing[
 num2 = Table[A = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> -a[2 i - 1],
                               {i_, j_} /; j == i -> a[2 i] + a[2 i - 1],
                               {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> -a[2 i]}, {n, n}];
              A[[All, 1]] = SparseArray[{{i_} /; i == 1 -> a[1]}, n];
              Det[A], {n, nmax}];
 den2 = Table[A = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> -a[2 i - 1],
                               {i_, j_} /; j == i -> a[2 i] + a[2 i - 1],
                               {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> -a[2 i]}, {n, n}];
              Det[A], {n, nmax}];
]
```

> 11.9063 s

```
a[x_] := ToExpression[SubscriptBox["a", ToString[x]]]
nmax = 40;
Timing[
 num3 = Table[Sum[Product[a[2 j - 1], {j, 1, n - i}] 
                  Product[a[2 j], {j, n - i + 1, n}],
                 {i, 0, n - 1}], {n, nmax}];
 den3 = Table[Sum[Product[a[2 j - 1], {j, 1, n - i}] 
                  Product[a[2 j], {j, n - i + 1, n}],
                 {i, 0, n}], {n, nmax}];
]
```

> 0.546875 s

```
Simplify[num1 == num2 == num3 && den1 == den2 == den3]
```

> True

it's deduced that the three formulations considered lead to the same result for every `n` from `1` to `40`, but by comparing the execution times it can also be deduced that they aren't equally efficient.

Therefore, assuming the *Wikipedia* [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Determinant) correct, writing:

```
a[x_] := ToExpression[SubscriptBox["a", ToString[x]]]
nmax = 100;


f[n_] := Sum[Product[a[2 j - 1], {j, 1, n - i}] 
             Product[a[2 j], {j, n - i + 1, n}], 
             {i, 0, n - 1}];
Norm[
 FullSimplify[
  Join[{f[1] - a[1]},
       {f[2] - a[1] (a[3] + a[4])},
       Table[f[n] - (a[2 n] + a[2 n - 1]) f[n - 1] +
                     a[2 n - 1] a[2 n - 2] f[n - 2],
             {n, 3, nmax}]]]]


f[n_] := Sum[Product[a[2 j - 1], {j, 1, n - i}] 
             Product[a[2 j], {j, n - i + 1, n}], 
             {i, 0, n}];
Norm[
 FullSimplify[
  Join[{f[1] - a[1] - a[2]},
       {f[2] - (a[1] + a[2]) (a[3] + a[4]) + a[2] a[3]},
       Table[f[n] - (a[2 n] + a[2 n - 1]) f[n - 1] +
                     a[2 n - 1] a[2 n - 2] f[n - 2],
             {n, 3, nmax}]]]]
```

> 0

> 0

we can see that your formulation verifies the *recurrence relation* for every `n` from `1` to `100` (we could also go further but I don't see the reason). Of course we haven't proved anything, but now it's evident that the calculations coincide.

Up to now everything has been focused on the computation of `x1`, but with a slight generalization of these formulations, all `n` solutions can be obtained. Checks from `1` to `40` are as follows:

```
a[x_] := ToExpression[SubscriptBox["a", ToString[x]]]
nmax = 40;
Timing[
 Monitor[
  Norm[
   Table[
    A = SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j == i - 1 -> -a[2 i - 1],
                     {i_, j_} /; j == i -> a[2 i] + a[2 i - 1],
                     {i_, j_} /; j == i + 1 -> -a[2 i]}, {n, n}];
    B = SparseArray[{{i_} /; i == 1 -> a[1]}, n];
    tab = Table[Sum[Product[a[2 k - 1], {k, 1, n - j}] 
                    Product[a[2 k], {k, n - j + 1, n}],
                   {j, 0, n - i}], {i, 0, n}];
    X = tab[[2 ;; n + 1]]/tab[[1]];
    Norm[FullSimplify[A.X - B]], {n, nmax}]],
  Row[{ProgressIndicator[n, {1, nmax}], n}, " "]]]
```

> {17.7656, 0}

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your effort and answer. I'm not sure, what you are showing here. Are you saying, that my suggested formula has slower/faster computing time than the formula on Wikipedia?

Comment: This is amazing! Actually, I was able to prove my formula with the recurrence formula and induction. To find the proof, I started with small numbers of $n$. I was recognizing, that almost half of the sum is vanishing, when calculating the formula. I think, most likely, this is due to the specific case. However, one might find a formula for general tridiagonal matrices, too. I might give an update on this. Thank you so much again for your effort. This is very insightful!